# Placing text below other text

Tags: cjk, stacking-symbols

How can I place some text centered below other text on the line?

I want to create similar to results to what is found in the `ruby` package, but instead of placing text above, the extra text is put below the baseline text. In the source code (see [ruby.sty](http://mirrors.ctan.org/language/chinese/CJK/cjk-4.8.2/texinput/ruby.sty)), I think I have found the code which places `#2` above `#1` in `\ruby{}{}`:

```
{\@tempdimc \f@size\p@
\@tempdimc \rubysize\@tempdimc
\sbox\z@{\vrule\@height.7\baselineskip\@depth\z@\@width\z@ #1}
\sbox\@tempboxa{\fontsize{\@tempdimc}{1.2\@tempdimc}\selectfont
    \vrule\@height\z@\@depth.3\baselineskip\@width\z@ #2}
```

- It is possible that `ruby.sty` already provides this feature, but I could not find any mention of this in the documentation (see [ruby.txt](http://ftp.ctex.org/mirrors/CTAN/language/chinese/CJK/cjk-4.8.2/doc/ruby.txt)).

I have also tried these, but the results are a bit different:

- `$\stackrel[below]{above}{middle}$`, but I do not need any text above.
- `$\underbrace{above}_{\hbox{below}}$`, but I do not need the underbrace.

I would prefer if the format and distance copied that of `\ruby{}{}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may require some tweaking when using different font sizes, but it seems sufficient in terms of the standard `article` document class, as shown in the following minimal example:

[image: \ruby duplicate with top/bottom text]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ruby}% http://ctan.org/pkg/cjk
\usepackage{lmodern}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lm

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\rubytop}[2]{%
  \@tempdimc \f@size\p@
  \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
    \fontsize{.4\@tempdimc}{.48\@tempdimc}\selectfont%
    \setlength{\normalbaselineskip}{0pt}#1\\[-4.3pt]
    #2
  \end{tabular}%
}
\newcommand{\rubybot}[2]{%
  \@tempdimc \f@size\p@
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
    #2\\[-6.7pt]
    \fontsize{.4\@tempdimc}{.48\@tempdimc}\selectfont%
    \setlength{\normalbaselineskip}{0pt}#1
  \end{tabular}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
one \ruby{one}{two} two \ruby{two}{one} one \rubytop{one}{two} two \rubybot{two}{one} one
\end{document}
```

The two new commands provided are `\rubytop{<top>}{<bot>}` and `\rubybot{<bot>}{<top>}`. The former duplicates `\ruby{<bot>}{<top>}` but uses a `tabular`, while the latter reverses the process.

[`ruby`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/language/chinese/CJK/cjk-4.8.2/texinput/ruby.sty) is not required if using `\rubytop` and `\rubybot`, nor does it have all the other fancy `\ruby` add-ons (like kern checking). The macros merely duplicate the output.